# Sorting child elements with lxml based on attribute value

Tags: python, xml, sorting, lxml

I'm trying to sort some child elements in a document based on an attribute value, and while the actual sorted function seems to be working, the splicing of the newly sorted elements doesn't seem to be.

```
from lxml import etree

def getkey(elem):
    # Used for sorting elements by @LIN.
    # returns a tuple of ints from the exploded @LIN value
    # '1.0' -> (1,0)
    # '1.0.1' -> (1,0,1)
    return tuple([int(x) for x in elem.get('LIN').split('.')])

xml_str = """<Interface>
                <Header></Header>
                <PurchaseOrder>
                    <LineItems>
                        <Line LIN="2.0"></Line>
                        <Line LIN="3.0"></Line>
                        <Line LIN="1.0"></Line>
                    </LineItems>
                </PurchaseOrder>
            </Interface>"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
lines = root.findall("PurchaseOrder/LineItems/Line")
lines[:] = sorted(lines, key=getkey)
res_lines = [x.get('LIN') for x in lines]
print res_lines

print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

When I execute the above code I will see the `lines` list did sort correctly as it prints `['1.0', '2.0', '3.0']`. However the XML tree isn't updated as tostring() prints out the below.

```
<Interface>
  <Header/>
  <PurchaseOrder>
    <LineItems>
      <Line LIN="2.0"/>
      <Line LIN="3.0"/>
      <Line LIN="1.0"/>
    </LineItems>
  </PurchaseOrder>
</Interface>
```

I got the idea for how to sort from http://effbot.org/zone/element-sort.htm, which says that the splicing should be all that I need to update the element order, but that doens't seem to be the case. I realise lxml is not 100% compatible with elementtree, so as a sanity check I replaced the lxml import with elementtree and got the exact same results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will sort and write the output:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("in.xml")

def getkey(elem):
    # Used for sorting elements by @LIN.
    # returns a tuple of ints from the exploded @LIN value
    # '1.0' -> (1,0)
    # '1.0.1' -> (1,0,1)
    return float(elem.get('LIN'))

container = tree.find("PurchaseOrder/LineItems")

container[:] = sorted(container, key=getkey)

tree.write("new.xml")
```

Or using your own code to print:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

def getkey(elem):
    # Used for sorting elements by @LIN.
    # returns a tuple of ints from the exploded @LIN value
    # '1.0' -> (1,0)
    # '1.0.1' -> (1,0,1)
    return float(elem.get('LIN'))

root = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
lines = root.find("PurchaseOrder/LineItems")
lines[:] = sorted(lines, key=getkey)
```

Output:

```
In [12]: print (etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
        <Interface>
            <Header/>
                <PurchaseOrder>
                    <LineItems>
                        <Line LIN="1.0"/>
                    <Line LIN="2.0"/>
                        <Line LIN="3.0"/>
                        </LineItems>
                </PurchaseOrder>
            </Interface>
```

The key is  `root.find("PurchaseOrder/LineItems")`, you want to find the `LineItems` element and sort that.

Comment: Ahh, yes of course. I was naively thinking that since it was a list of references that magically somehow it would adjust the order, however I see now how silly that idea was. Thank you.